# Check if X server is started in a script under rc.local

Tags: bash, autostart, xset

I have a script that depends on X server is started. So in the script, I check if X is started with the while loop below:

```
while xset q; do
  sleep 1
done
```

Everything works well if I run this script manually. But if it's started from rc.local during system start, it sticks in the loop.

How to check if X is started in the script under rc.local?

Comment: FYI: This kind of keep-alive listener is not necessary when using the systemd tools (instead of rc.local) already on your system.